# Expanding on this character lookahead regex to also work with a string

Tags: regex

I am using regex to pull out a unix time from an abbr object:

```
<abbr data-utime="1468050300" class="timestamp">10:45</abbr>
```

With regex I have learned how to do it with a negative and positive lookahead using the double quotes:

```
(?!")[0-9].*?(?=") // returns 1468050300
```

This works ok, but wonder now how would I go about matching more specifically?

e.g. not just doing a negative lookahead on the first "(double quote) but also including the string 'data-utime='

If I want the utime but the attribute is no longer the first set of quotes:

```
<abbr class="timestamp" data-utime="1468050300" >10:45</abbr>
```

Then this regex no longer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't use a regex which matches the attribute `data-utime` by name, e.g.

```
data-utime="(.*?)"
```

This would be robust to the attribute changing relative position within the `<abbr>` tag, and you would not have to deal with negative and positive lookaheads.

If you find yourself having to write very complex regex to parse XML, then you should seriously consider using an XML parser instead, which is a better tool for this.

**Demo at:**

## Regex101

Comment: One comment: The question mark appearing after `.*` makes the regex parser stop after finding the _first_ quotation mark.  Remove it and test it, you will see that without the question mark the match will be greedy, and it will eat _everything_ until the last quotation mark (which isn't what you want).

Comment: That is really helpful. Been trying to understand what being greedy was. You explained it well!